# how to add ListArray<String> data to android:tag property of spinner control programmatically?

Tags: android

Hi i am new to android my requirement is to add ListArray data into Spinner control android:tag property and fetch when user select something from Spinner control

How to do this programmatically in android please help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `setViewBinder` interface to set the tag of the views inside the Spinner while loading it with data. You then need to implement the `OnItemSelectedListener` interface to get the tag of the view selected.